# div element does not act like a block when specified

Tags: css

Ok I have 2 problems with my aligning.

first of all, 2 borders to the left of my div are being created, and I don't get why that is. I only want one border to be created. And the width is 1px, so it shouldn't act like that ?

The second problem is that the purple div (there are 2 at bottom), which I didn't include in this pic but it is basically a div with this class:

```
.reviewsContent {
    clear:both;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left: 25px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

This div ( purple) should not not overlap with the blue div as it is a block, but it does..

Thanks !

[larger picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFXOV.jpg)

this is the html code

```
<div class="productWrapper">
        <div class="productName">LG 6.3 Cu. Ft. Self-Clean Smooth Top Range <br> <span class="categoryText">Dishwashers</span></div>
        <div class="productContent">
            <div class="subtitleText">Product Description</div>
            <p class="productText">
                some product descrip tion some product descrip tion some product descrip tion some product descrip tion some product descrip tion 
                some product descrip tion some product descrip tion some product descrip tion
            </p>
            <div class="subtitleText">Product Details</div>
            <p class="productText">
                Width: <br>
                Height: <br>
                Weights: <br>

            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="productImage">
            <img class='productImage' src='images/c000002.jpg'>
            <div class="productImageInfo">In-stock: 10 ................................... ADD CART BUTTON</div>
        </div>

        <div class="reviewsContent">Reviawe fawe a..</div>
        <div class="reviewsContent">Reviews..</div>
    </div>
```

and this is the css sheet

```
.productWrapper {
    /*background-color: red;*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    /*height:1000px;*/
    margin-left: 230px;
    padding-top:10px;
    /*font-family: "Open Sans",Verdana,sans-serif;*/
    font-family: calibri;
    color: #000000;
}

.productName {
    font-size: 24px;
    //font-size: 22px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #444444;
    /*background-color:green;*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #E4E4E4;
}

.productContent {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:25px;
    width: 350px;
    border: none;
}

.productImage {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 330px;
    max-width: 330px;
    height: 330px;
    max-height: 360px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-left: 8px;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-color: #E4E4E4;
    /*float: right;
    //padding-left: 5px;
    background-color:blue;*/
}

.productImage img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    /*float:right;*/
    /*background-color:blue;*/
}

.productImageInfo {
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: auto;
}

.reviewsContent {
    clear:both;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left: 25px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: yeap sorry, just upped this. should be clearer now.

Comment: comments in css must be of the form `/* ... */`. "`//`" does not work.

Comment: yes, i know that // are not valid but they get ignored, and its faster.

Comment: if you right-click on the element and do "inspect element" you can see the computed styles and see if your `display: block` is taking effect, or get clues as to why it is not.

Comment: @PenguinSource plz check if you don't have two divs that are beside others in way that may the border in the right of the right div displayed as it is the border of the div you are facing problem with :)

Then about divs try to use z-index :)

Comment: hmmm... still seems like a bad idea to me.  Many (most?) decent editors should give you an easy way to comment a line like `ctrl`+`/`

Comment: Yes, inspecting the element shows that the display: block is actually invalid, so that makes sense, but i'm not sure why it is invalid and if the inspector does show it, where is it? I will look into n++'s way of commenting, thanks ! @Last Breath, I am not sure exactly what you mean. The left div (productContent), has no border. The right div (productImage) does, so shouldn't there only be one border displayed?

Comment: @PenguinSource : If you have 2 divs adjacent beside each other and each div has its own border so the display seem to be as border of 2px width but you told me that the div at the left of your div have no border but the right one has so i think this is not your case because if that must happen you will see a border of width 2px at the right side not the left side so we need more code to stand up over your problem :)

Comment: And about your div and your invalid block display try to find if your div inherit another display property from any parent element :)

Comment: Yes, I understand about the border problem; not the case now but good to know.

About the div block, I don't see why it would inherit from a parent as I set the display: block so it should override it. 

Are there cases where the parent's inheritance is forced and overrides the display set in the div itself?

I added the html and css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see there are two things wrong with this so far:

First you have applied the `productImage` class to botht the `div` and the `img` tags. This is why you have two borders. The `div` gets one and the `img` gets another from the `productImage` class.

The reason why the divs do not seem to be clearing each other is because of where they are in the DOM.

The review divs are in fact clearing the `productImage` div, but you explicitly gave it a height that is not large enough to contain your image and your info. Since the info is inside the `productImage` div, it is not cleared because it is not considered when the reviews are laid out, I think.

If you increase the height of the `productImage` class to 380px and you take the `productImage` class off of the div, [then I think you get exactly what you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/gvRGq/5/embedded/result/)

Bear in mind there is still a bit of a visual break where the image sits because the background of the image is white and the background of the page is grey, but the border is gone.